# Using JSON to manage data from multiple tables (PHP + MySQL)

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, serialization

I'm currently working on a project that involves an Android app and MySQL.
I need to get data from a MySQL database (Which is located on a local Server, I'm using Apache), the thing is, I've have already done this by getting data from a SINGLE table and then with a class that implements "Serializable" I'm able to "use" the data. 
Now, here is my .php working

```
<?PHP
include_once("connection.php");

$query = "SELECT E.Nombre, COUNT(C.Id_Estudiante_FK) AS Cuenta
FROM Estudiante E INNER JOIN Comentario C ON E.Id_Estudiante=C.Id_Estudiante_FK
GROUP BY E.Id_Estudiante
ORDER BY COUNT(C.Id_Estudiante_FK) DESC"; 

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

It returns back the data I need already encoded, my question is how can I manage that information I'm getting, is it possible to just create another class that implements Serializable having as attributes the rows I'm returning (Which are **"Nombre"** and **"Cuenta"**)?

Here is the php I use for the query that only involves one table (Already works, and I'm able to "use" the data):

```
<?PHP
include_once("connection.php");

if(isset($_POST['txttipooferta'])){
$idtipooferta=$_POST['txttipooferta'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM oferta WHERE Id_Tipo_Oferta_FK=$idtipooferta AND Cupos>0 ORDER BY Id_Oferta DESC"; 

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($data);
}
?>
```

[And here is the class that I use to manage the data that I get from the .php, note that the atributes of the class match the one the table "Oferta" has (as the .php's query is "SELECT *")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNaQQ.png)

Would my problem be solved by just creating another class that implements Serializable and has as attributes **"Nombre"** and **"Cuenta"**?

Thank you!

Comment: 'Serializable' you are talking about android class implements?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Seems like in the time you were waiting for an answer you could just try it and see if it works.  Is there something preventing you from trying it out?

Comment: Yes, I will try out to see if it works but the thing is I'm currently focused on other part of the project, this thing is like a "plus" I'll add to it...I have the intentions to try it and then updating the question with my results :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in a comment before, this particular problem I had was a "plus" I would add to my project, I was focused on other more important parts of it therefore I did not have time to check on this.
The answer is yes, you can just create a class that implements Serializable and matches the attributes you are encoding, below you can see my .php and my Java Class that work:

```
<?PHP
include_once("connection.php");

$query = "SELECT E.Nombre, COUNT(C.Id_Estudiante_FK) AS Cuenta
FROM Estudiante E INNER JOIN Comentario C ON E.Id_Estudiante=C.Id_Estudiante_FK
GROUP BY E.Id_Estudiante
ORDER BY COUNT(C.Id_Estudiante_FK) DESC"; 

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

The query returns two fields "Nombre" and "Cuenta".

[And here you have my Java class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g10MM.png)

Hope this helps somebody else! :)